# How to make version numbers into decimal numbers in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Is there any way to make version numbers into decimal numbers? It doesnt need to round up or down, I just need it to display the first two values.
eg:
5.6.49 => 5.6  or
10.3.25 => 10.3

Comment: Yes. What have you tried? Where are you reading the numbers from? What do you need to do with them? Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

There's always `sed`

```sh
echo '5.6.49' | sed -E 's/([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*).*/\1/'
5.6
```

Answer (score 0):

With cut you can select only the first two numbers:

```
cut -d"." -f 1,2
```

Here `-d` switch defines the delimiter that is used here, `-f` switch select the fields that are separated using the delimeter.

For example

```
echo "5.2.3.5" |cut -d"." -f 1,2
5.2
```

Answer (score 0):

or awk:

```
echo '5.6.49' | awk -F. '{print $1 "." $2}'
5.6
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple parameter expansion ideas:

Assuming OP knows the version string contains only 2 decimals:

```
$ xall=5.6.49
$ xdec="${xall%.*}"
$ echo "${xdec}"
5.6
```

If OP knows version string contains 3 or more decimals **or** OP does not know how many decimals exist in the version string:

```
$ xall='5.6.49.92'

$ x1="${xall%%.*}"
$ echo "${x1}"
5

$ x2="${xall#*.}"
$ echo "${x2}"
6.49.92

$ x2="${x2%%.*}"
$ echo "${x2}"
6

$ xdec="${x1}.${x2}"
$ echo "${xdec}"
5.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use variable substitution with [shell patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
$ VAR=5.6.49
$ echo ${VAR%.*}
$ 5.6
```

Answer (score 0):

xargs and printf

```
echo "10.3.25" | xargs printf "%g"
```